# Send config files to/from Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that can save/load a config file (json)

I want to send this file and get it from a device to another device
So I added this possibility so the app can send to gmail or whatever

```
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
                            shareIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, getContentResolver().getType(fileUri));
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
```

I added to manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

edit: I also have in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.xxxx.yyyyy.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

I added the lines below to handle the intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
         //????
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receive the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

It even not propose me my App as a possible App that can be used to open the file.
Why?

but if I share some text (from Viber or...), I see that it enters to the code looking for "Text/*"

**What I need is to propose my App as a handler for Text Files**

Comment: Where is the last piece of code you are checking ? On the second device ?

Comment: yes, on the receiver device, which also run the same App, it must get the file from download directory (via en explorer or gmail who will send it to the App if the user click the file)

Comment: One Possibility check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. There are couple of other thing you need to check in the last piece of code on what action you are doing the check

Comment: I can access the files with         <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.embesystems.inductionmotor.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>   I also added : 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have set "text/plain" as MIME type in intent filter so you must set shareIntent's type  to "text/plain".

In other words, make sure that  `getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)` does return "text/plain" which may not be the case for your code.

So it's better if you call `setDataAndType` as followed:

```
shareIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it: The right intent is ACTION_VIEW

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>-->
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```